# How to decompress .deb file using php?

Tags: php, debian

How to decompress .deb file using php?? .deb is DEBIAN file.
I try to run code but unsucessfully:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('file.zip');
if ($res === TRUE)
{
$zip->extractTo('/myzips/extract_path/');
$zip->close();
echo 'woot!';
}
else
{
echo 'doh!';
}
?>
```

Extract it using 7zip very easy but I dont know extract .deb online using php. Please help me.

Thank you!!

Comment: Need to post at least something you have tried. There are compression tools in PHP. Or you can execute a command to the shell. Please edit and add code examples.

Answer (score 0):

.deb files are just **ar** archives, with the following contents, according the Debian Policy Manual:

- `debian-binary` (debian version of package)
- `control.tar.gz` (package meta-information for dpkg)
- `data.tar.gz` (files/directories to install the package)

The file extensions of control and data can be tar, tar.gz, tar.xz, tar.bz2 etc.

So, using native tools in a unix environment, after extract the ar file (.deb), you will need check what kind of file and the right tool and parameters to extract. I.e: `tar zxf control.tar.gz`, `tar xjf control.tar.bz2`, and so on.

Or you can try this: https://github.com/cmanley/PHP-SevenZipArchive. 7zip also support **ar** files and many more formats, well, you know :). But you will need the 7zip installed on the server.